# DHCP giving out addresses on only one interface, Juniper EX2200

Tags: dhcp, juniper, juniper-ex

My EX2200 is successfully giving out ip addresses over DHCP on interface ge-0/0/42. And only on that interface. Here is the config as I have it for that port, and the one next to it:

```
ge-0/0/42 {
     unit 0 {
          family inet {
               address 10.0.0.149/32
          }
     }

ge-0/0/44 {
     unit 0 {
          family inet {
               address 10.0.0.151/32
          }
     }
```

Now why is 42 working properly and 44 not? I did a show configuration, and I can't see any differences between the ports. Anyone got any ideas? I have plenty of addresses in the pool, and I've tested multiple devices on that port, so it gives them out fine.

```
set system services dhcp pool 10.0.0.0/24 address-range low 10.0.0.2
set system services dhcp pool 10.0.0.0/24 address-range high 10.0.0.252
set system services dhcp pool 10.0.0.0/24 router 10.0.0.1
```

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to include "show configuration | display inheritance | display set | match dhcp"

The interface configuration by itself is not going to be enough to answer your question.   The above request should be enough, or at the very least a starting point.

Comment: Done. Any other relevant info needed?

Comment: It might just be easier to throw your entire configuration in here - just "show configuration" - feel free to obscure public IP's if you're concerned about that.

Comment: I'm surprised either worked since the interfaces are configured as /32s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the long wait. I've solved the problem by now, and everything was wrong. I had to reload the factory config and start from scratch. In this case, it was just a matter of not setting up my interfaces properly and looking for answers on the wrong switch. And then messing with the config to death.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: Sorry about this!